# nested recyclerview using paging adapter (paging 3) show wrong image after scrolling

Tags: android, android-paging, nestedrecyclerview, android-diffutils, coil

How to solve the child adapter image that changes and show wrong images after scrolling?

this is my code

**Parent Data Class**

```
data class Review(
   val author: String,
   val date: String,
   val rating: Float,
   val comment: String,
   val images: List<Image>)
```

**Child Data Class**

For author and comment, I only take it from the parent data class

```
data class Image(
   var author: String? = null,
   var comment: String? = null,
   val large: String,
   val thumbnail: String)
```

**ParentAdapter**

```
class ReviewAdapter(private val callback: ProductReviewImageAdapterCallback) :
PagingDataAdapter<Review, ReviewAdapter.ListViewHolder>(DIFF_CALLBACK) {

private val viewPool = RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool()

private val imageAdapter: ProductReviewImageAdapter by lazy {
    ProductReviewImageAdapter(callback)
}

companion object {
    private val DIFF_CALLBACK = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Review>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Review, newItem: Review): Boolean {
            return oldItem.author == newItem.author
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Review, newItem: Review): Boolean {
            return oldItem.comment == newItem.comment
        }
    }
}


inner class ListViewHolder(itemBinding: ItemProductReviewBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemBinding.root) {
    val binding = ItemProductReviewBinding.bind(itemBinding.root)
    fun bind(data: Review, position: Int) {
      with(binding) {
            if (data.images.isEmpty()) {
                rvImageReview.gone()
            } else {
                setupImagesRecyclerView(rvImageReview)
                rvImageReview.visible()
                imageAdapter.differ.submitList(data.images)
            }

            tvNameReviewer.text = data.author
            tvReviewDesc.text = data.comment
            tvDateReview.text = data.date
            ratingBarReview.rating = data.rating

        }
    }
}


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ListViewHolder =
    ListViewHolder(
        ItemProductReviewBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
    )

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ListViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val review = getItem(position)

    if (review != null) {
        holder.bind(review, position)
    }
}

private fun setupImagesRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
    recyclerView.apply {
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
        adapter = imageAdapter
        setRecycledViewPool(viewPool)
        setItemViewCacheSize(20)
    }
}
```

}

**ChildAdapter**

```
class ProductReviewImageAdapter(private val callback: ProductReviewImageAdapterCallback) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductReviewImageAdapter.ListViewHolder>() {
private val diffCallback = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Image>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(
        oldItem: Image,
        newItem: Image
    ): Boolean {
        return oldItem.author == newItem.author
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(
        oldItem: Image,
        newItem: Image
    ): Boolean {
        return oldItem.comment == newItem.comment
    }

}

val differ = AsyncListDiffer(this, diffCallback)

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ListViewHolder =
    ListViewHolder(
        ItemImageBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
    )

override fun getItemCount(): Int = differ.currentList.size

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ListViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(differ.currentList[position], position)
}

inner class ListViewHolder(itemBinding: ItemImageBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemBinding.root) {
    private val itemBinding = ItemImageBinding.bind(itemBinding.root)
    fun bind(data: Image, position: Int) {
        with(itemBinding) {

            image.loadImageRoundedCorner(data.thumbnail)

            image.setOnClickListener {
                callback.onProductReviewImageClicked(position, differ.currentList)
            }

        }

    }
}
```

}

**Before scrolling**

on first load, the first position data displays the appropriate image

[before scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETYEN.png)

**After a bit scrolling**

the image in the first position data changes to the image in the next data

[after a bit scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAjp5.png)

**Scroll to last data/page**

the last image shows an unsuitable image

[scroll to last data/page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YL4e9.png)

*Note

- there is only 5 data, and only first and last data contains image
- The image in the first position data should be a person image and the last position image should be a pink image
- I use [Coil](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/) as the image loader and have used the ImageView.clear() method before loading the image

Thanks in advance, sorry if my english is bad. I'm not a native speaker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

Fixed :
it turned out that it was only wrong at the time of adapter initialization, the adapter should be initialized in onBindViewHolder, not in the parent adapter so that not all items have the same adapter which causes all data to change